# Jest: Mocking Relative Import From Node Module (Axios)

Tags: mocking, jestjs, axios

I'm testing my library that wraps Axios, setting different parameters and configuration options. What I'm trying to see is whether these configuration options are correctly applied and the final request will look as expected.

My preference would be to inspect the final request created just before it's sent. After looking through the code, it seems that's not going to work: the request is built and sent within the same function (the promise executor in `httpAdapter` from `axios/lib/adapters/http.js`). If I'm wrong and someone knows how to do it, I'd love to hear how!

It seems to me that the next best thing is to inspect the `config` passed to `httpAdapter` (or to `dispatchRequest` - `axios/lib/core/dispatchRequest.js`) - after all, the library will test to make sure the request is correctly created from it. I'm not sure that's possible either, since it's all "webpacked"... Can it be done? If so, how?

If there's any other ideas as to how to best go about this, I'd be happy to have your input!

### Update

I've just stumbled upon solution for my primary problem: installing a request interceptor will give me the the incoming config.

I'm still very interested in whether the mocking can be done, though!

Comment: not sure if I got it completely. you may mock axios with `jest.mock("axios");` but you will need to provide appropriate mocks for those axios' methods your code relies on(I mean on calls' results). You may mock underlying XHR/fetch with something like `fetch-mock` package or alike. You may even use something request-source-agnostic like `nock`. And there you will be able validating if request was as you expected. There are a lot of approaches and question seems too broad to me.

Comment: Sorry my question was unclear. I'm trying to test whether my wrapper configures axios correctly such that the requests sent have the expected headers and default parameters set. If I mock axios completely, I don't think I'd be able to do that. I'll look into `nock` then, what you're saying sounds like that may be a way to go.